# AFNetworking несколько запростов на одном view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, сеть, клиент-сервер, afnetworking

Здравствуйте!

Допустим есть rest-сервер. Допустим есть:

POST/auth 
GET/data1 
GET/data2 
GET/dat3

При в ходе в приложение пользователь попадает на экран авторизации. ВВодит логин пароль и дергается POST/auth. Затем после успешной авторизации пользователь попадает на экран, который должне отобразить какую то информацию о пользователе. Эту информацию я получаю из GET/dataN соответственно.

Как было бы правильно осуществить все три запроса в одном контроллере? Насколько правильно бы было сделать так:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 ...

 [[APISerever sharedInstancce] requestData1WithDelegate:self];
 [[APISerever sharedInstancce] requestData2WithDelegate:self];
 [[APISerever sharedInstancce] requestData3WithDelegate:self];

}

- (void)requestDidFinish: (APIServerResponse *)response {
   switch(response.type) {
     case RESPONSE_TYPE_DATA1: {
         break;
     }
     case RESPONSE_TYPE_DATA2: {
         break;
     }
     case RESPONSE_TYPE_DATA2: {
         break;
     }
   }
}
```

Если не правильно то как лучше сделать? Спасибо!

Comment: А при чём тут AFNetworking?

Comment: Почему у вас пользователь в процессе переходит на несколько разных экранов, а контроллер у Вас для запросов один?

Comment: Ваш код будет отправит запросы параллельно и вы получите ошибку авторизации. Надо вызывать их "матрешкой" - получив положительный ответ авторизации, вызывать из него (из функции обрабатывающий ответ) запрос данных о пользователе, и в свою очередь из ответа данных - вывод на экран.